# Bintray dependencies won't download in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, pom.xml, kotlin, bintray

I created a simple kotlin project in IntelliJ 2017.1

I wanted to add dependency to this library for starters: https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed

I added maven framework, and edited pom.xml so it looks like below. I removed kotlin config entries for simplicity.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <id>exposed</id>
            <name>exposed</name>
            <url>https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.exposed</groupId>
            <artifactId>exposed</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jre8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Kotlin libraries got downloaded and I see them in external libraries. Unfortunately that's not the case for Exposed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined that you want `pom` not `jar`.

Import your dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jetbrains.exposed</groupId>
  <artifactId>exposed</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.6</version>
</dependency>
```